# how to run Metro Apps from the Desktop in Win8.1

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

Im developing a Metro app based on WinJS-HTML5-CSS3

all the metro apps installed and developed are stored in one location

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps

there if I look for my metro app and enter inside I found my same folder distribution, however if I open default.html my metro app is displayed on IE11 not in the same metro environment

Is there a way to execute my metro app from the desktop, I mean like a executable, what I want is to take my folder with me and then run this "executable"

thanks in advance for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a supported way to execute a Windows Store Application developed using the Windows Runtime on the desktop. While you can "side-load" an application in some instances ([TechNet reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx)), WinRT applications must be "installed" to run.